# Deploying website along with web application

Tags: django, web-applications, deployment, paas

I'm in the process of researching possible ways to deploy web site along with a web application. I'm using Python/Django with gunicorn as the webserver and AngularJS (front-end) for the web application, which will be deployed on some PaaS like Heroku.

The web site (mainly used for marketing purposes), what are some recommending ways to deploy this site along with the web application? My concern is that users hitting the site will slow down performance for users of the web application. If I'm using Django for the web application backend, is it ok to use Django for the web site and deploy it...say on a different port/server? Perhaps use nginx to serve just static content for the site? What are some best practices out there on solving this? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your "web site" is all static files, could you load it all up into a single folder and have it served directly by nginx?

Alternatively, you could look at something like [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com/)